# How to push a new viewController when clicking on a tableView cell?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift5, xcode13

I thought that I had this code correct; however, when I run it, I click on the cell and nothing happens. The code that I have to push the view controller is in my didSelectRowAt func.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let vc = ChatViewController()
        vc.title = "Jenny Smith"
        vc.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here and why a click doesn't show a new ViewController?

Comment: What you have looks correct to me.   Is the `navigationController` nil?  If you set a breakpoint in this code, does the debugger stop in this code when you select a table view item?

Comment: Are you sure you have a nav controller?  Also set a background colour for vc.view, just to make sure you aren't loading a clear view and not seeing it.

Comment: tableview.delegate = self have you did this?

Comment: @flanker a nav controller for for the vc that I'm trying to switch to or a nav controller for the vc that I'm writing code to?

Comment: Would be the same for both - it manages the VCs pushed to / popped from its stack.  As a quick and dirty test, change `navigationController?.pushViewController` to `navigationController!.pushViewController` as then if it's nil it will crash.  (this is jus for debugging, not for production!)

Answer (score 0):

You must try this to solve the problem, if there is any issues else you can ask me

```
let VC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatViewController") as! ChatViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: false)
```